# Are there any gay characters in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

If you discount species that only have one gender (which are homosexual by default), and species that change their appearance or body (like Changelings and Trills), are there any homosexual characters in the prime universe?

I am aware of Ezri and Lita being homosexual or bisexual in the Mirror Universe, but I am interested in the **canon prime universe**.

This question is explicitly about homosexuality. I am not focusing on those who are bisexual characters (there is one, Garak) or transgender characters (there is an entire episode covering that topic).  This is also not a question about the legal status of LGBT peoples in Star Trek - it's about **if there were any on screen characters who were homosexual**. (Identified as such on screen or in the background by the actor or producers.)

Comment: [Homosexuality in Star Trek](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/homosexuality.htm)

Comment: I've edited the question slightly; to my mind now it isn't a dupe

Comment: I doubt it. If you exclude the revolting "must make character evil therefore gay" from the mirror universe.

Comment: In the future no-one cares who's gay or not, and they think the 21st century obsession with it is laughably primitive

Comment: “I am not focusing on those who are bisexual characters (there is one, Garak)” — does Garak’s sexuality ever come up? I remember he seemed to be into Ziyal, and a romance with a woman was mentioned in [A Stitch in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Stitch_in_Time_(novel)).

Comment: [There is now!](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/jul/21/john-cho-gay-kiss-cut-star-trek-beyond)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Only if you count the JJ Verse as star trek.  I do not.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Garak has been '[Word of Gay](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGay)'d by various people involved with the show; https://bi-characters.tumblr.com/post/127547609408/character-elim-garak-appears-in-star-trek-deep

Answer (score 8):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sexuality) doesn't mention many cases, explaining:

> Unless Human nature has changed between modern times and the era of
> Star Trek, there are probably many homosexual individuals throughout
> the Human culture of the future, but **they are rarely specified as such
> in any canon sense**

[This article](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/homosexuality.htm) mentions that **Lt. Hawk** from *First Contact* may have been gay:

> When "First Contact" was being produced in 1996, musings about the
> purportedly gay bridge officer Lt. Hawk set off a self-sustaining
> process, with new rumors cropping up every few days, even in
> mainstream print media. But Hawk ended up as a Star Trek default
> character who, as Rick Berman himself stated, is not supposed to be
> gay. Lt. Hawk was established as gay in the novel Section 31: Rogue
> though.

The same article also refers to the Mirror universe:

> Most prominently **Mirror Kira Nerys** (the Intendant) feels attracted to
> men and women alike. In addition, **Ezri Tigan** seems to be lesbian or
> bisexual in the Mirror Universe, and potentially Leeta as well (DS9:
> "The Emperor's New Cloak")

Out of canon, we have Yoshi Mishima in the *Starfleet Academy* comic [Culture Clash](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Culture_Clash), who was in a homosexual relationship ([Source](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Halakith))

Back to the original question though, the answer it seems is **no, there were *not* officially any on-screen homosexual characters in canon.**  Hawk's status is not confirmed, but he is the most likely candidate in the prime, canon universe.

Comment: @AdrianChazz Welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack and thank you for your effort. I've rolled it back, since it alters the existing content too much. I invite you to add it as an answer of your own instead. If you need to find what you've typed, look at [the revisions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/100625/revisions) (which can be found by clicking on _edited_). Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: well said. I am sick of all the requirements in media these days to explicitly mark x% of the cast as homosexual, y% as black, z% Asian, etc. etc.. Just because something isn't thrown in your face doesn't mean it's not there. I don't care if Picard is homosexual or what, it's not relevant for the character to know in any context except a homosexual porn flick.